# Sub menu in side menu

Tags: html, css

I did a menu in the left side of the screen that it's rotated but when I try to add a sub menu it appears in the top side of the menu and not in the bottom could someone help me?

```css
ul li{
 display:inline;
 padding: 0.4vw 0.7vw; 
}
nav {
  grid-area: menu;
  font-family: Karla;
  display: block;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a></li>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
      </div>
    </div>
    <li><a href="website.html">Website</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```css
 the top side of the menu and not in the bottom could someone help me?

ul li{
 display:inline;
 padding: 0.4vw 0.7vw; 
}
nav {
  grid-area: menu;
  font-family: Karla;
  display: block;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
      </div>
      <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a>      </li>
    </div>
    <li><a href="website.html">Website</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked but the sub menu displays in block and i wanted it to be inline when i change in the .dropdown to inline it doesn't show under "Porfólio" it goes way down what can I do to fix it?

Comment: I solved you issue , if worked then you can like it :)

Comment: that isn't what I'm looking for

Comment: can you show me what are you looking for? or you can explain me in detail

Answer (score 0):

you can add as many submenu items with this

```
        ul li{
            display:inline;
            padding: 0.4vw 0.7vw;   
        }
        nav {
          grid-area: menu;
          font-family: Karla;
          display: block;
          writing-mode: vertical-rl;
          transform: rotate(-180deg);
        }

        .dropdown {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
          display: none;
          position: absolute;
          padding-left: 100px
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
          display: block;
        }
```

```
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfólio</a></li>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> Link1</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <li><a href="website.html">Website</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
```